# Sql query returning unexpected result in PhP Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel for an API and I am trying to get a value from the Database and testing with postman, but when i try to do it it responds blank, and if i see the query being made it returns a ? where it should return a string

```
public function getUser(Request $request){
    $email = $request;
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    return $user;
    $response = User::find($user.id)->first();
    return json_encode((string) $response->get(), true);
}
```

[Postman response with first()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xbPE.png)

If i replace first() with toSql()

```
public function getUser(Request $request){
    $email = $request;
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->toSql();
    return $user;
    $response = User::find($user.id)->first();
    return json_encode((string) $response->get(), true);
}
```

[Postman response with toSql()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaD2b.png)

But if i do User::first() it works, and the $email is the right one too.

I am sorry if the title is misleading or if the question is wrongly made, i am new to this and didnt know where else to seek for help.

Edit: There is a user with the email i am trying to get

[Postman result with User::first()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY2KE.png)

Comment: is there $user with that email in database?

Comment: Yes, if i return the email i get "admin1@mail.pt", and if i retrieve the first row of the table i get the user with the same email because that is what i am trying to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly when you do `toSql()` it uses prepared statements, so `?` is a placeholder where the values will be placed later.

This part of the code does not make sense, request is an object and you cannot query by the request object. Either you do form input, query or json input and take it from there.

```
$email = $request;
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
```

How to get the input from form, json or query.

```
$email = $request->input($email);
```

In `Laravel` you don't have to worry about encoding so json_encode() is unnecessary.

Putting it all togheter imaginging the route like so `localhost/api/user?email=admin@yoursite.com`. Should be nothing more than.

```
public function show(Request $request) {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked with $request->email, i was doing $email = $request because i tought the $request was itself the email

Comment: A trick when debugging is to utilise dd() method to dump your variables and go through the different inputs :)